# jQuery-ui sortable - Again enable sortable after it has been disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, sortables

I have the following jQuery code:

```
var isOk = true;
$('#edit').click(function () {
    if (isOk) {
        $('table tbody').sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                $.ajax({
                    data: data,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'updatePagesOrder.php',
                    success: function (msg) { //re-number the rows from 1 to n
                        $('table > tbody tr').each(function (i) {
                            $(this).attr('id', 'item-' + (i + 1)); // use $(this) as a reference to current tr object
                        });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("An error occurred");
                    }
                });
            }
        }, "enable");
    }
    else {
        $("table tbody").unbind();
        $('table a').unbind();
    }
    isOk = !isOk;
```

In the code above `#edit` is a button, on the first click it cause the table rows to be sorable, and on the second click it disable the sortable option.

I want that on the third click the rows will be sortable again.
I tried the code above, but it didn't work.

Why? and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted... Great question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize the widget outside the click handler:

```
$('table tbody').sortable({
    disabled: true, // Initially disabled
    axis: 'y',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'updatePagesOrder.php',
            success: function (msg) { //re-number the rows from 1 to n
                $('table > tbody tr').each(function (i) {
                    $(this).attr('id', 'item-' + (i + 1)); // use $(this) as a reference to current tr object
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Then just toggle the "disabled" option when you click on the button.

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
    var table = $('table tbody');
    table.sortable('option', 'disabled', !table.sortable('option', 'disabled'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got an error  : "'undefined is not a function"

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery-UI library?

Comment: In the first line, and yes

Comment: That error means it's not finding the `sortable` method, and I can't explain why that would happen if the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries were successfully loaded. Do you have any other libraries that use `$` as their main function? You may need to use `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Comment: Here is a fiddle, can you take a look to see what's wrong pleas? http://jsfiddle.net/es9BH/1/

Comment: When I select jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI in the sidebar, the fiddle works. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/es9BH/2/

Comment: Thanks. But in the third and fourth click it seems that it doesn't work properly...

Comment: It's because of `$('table tbody').unbind()`. When I remove that it works on later clicks. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/es9BH/4/ Why are you doing that?

Comment: It's strange that I keep get the error "undefined is not a function" in my website, right after the sortable function. Because it worked befor and I didn't get this error....

Comment: Is your page accessible on the Internet?

Comment: Yes. I tried to add '$(document).ready(function () {...' befor the sorable function, and the error disappeared, but the script doesn't work

Comment: Oh my mistake it's on localhost, but it should work, the other jQuery functions work just fine...

Comment: If I can't see what you're doing, I can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I can't tell anything from that. I need to see what scripts you have loaded and the order that you're loading them.

Comment: This was a great answer. Helpful